# How to type keyof instace in JSDOC similarily to TS?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How can I type keyof instance in Javascript (JSDOC) similarily to Typescript?

TS is just fine:

```
const a1 = new Car('Audi A1', 4, Power.solar);
const a380 = new Plane('Airbus A380', 800, 4);

function showProperty<T>(thing: T, prop: keyof T) {
    console.log(`${String(prop)}:`, thing[prop]);
}

showProperty(a1, 'power');
showProperty(a380, 'engines');
```

link to [full TS code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gbwFDV9YA9shAC4BOArsCQWQBTJgC2ApgFzSlkqoA0+YAA5hgiEgE8OyCkwBGLMgEpMOPGpJIIAOgD6jVtAC80fSwDcqtbg2JtO4EJFjxRgcNESLagL6Xog7gA3MBIWaD1mdk5yHi88AMRg0PCHd2cpGXkyONxUFhITSLplbCs8MnyKMmRoGztTHOhfNTyC1KcJYpUy3AqSKpq63XaPcUbfXywWaSZoAAUCAHcFbvj8sgIQXj8AE0QWCBYtv1RIbbUITbAybd9QSBgAYWvoFgAPUOQdmAQeVdxCMRyFQaPRTBwuDx+CN0iZMgp+IIlgoOAtlkp-lYIBRBAoGJFoY5RopGupNLokejXJSFOM-AkkmEdDSyKjkdkTvl-OyuqUen0BrVycz2XTJvcoPNwMgwu9Pt84Eg0JjAVwQbR8awITE0IS0hIMnIEa80CgDoasiU-BccXjTHqOuISda8EMdNNUGaYMYPV66WoGSEmb6ZRALbTOQUQwdeS7epVqkLbLpoxAxVgsKqCmAAIyuGWLaDPegAcgAghQ9tAyzmS-wACz8NEKLSXcBKCxZ6BgADMAA4AAz5liFubSlh0cuIMiyCgwMv9gd16CDgcN51YABmFGQ1EQRE48CWcw2uLIEgAPLAAHx0GxoDiwRGnjgAaxY4gIm7gVrUqs2LBaCABCoHQAAGAAkGAAMo6qBAQEIIijeGwYH8PeqAANoIYIAC6zrikQbaAaALDXMUFgQEeiwnohCidLm-AliyJbOlRx6nvR4h0L2g5MamrEWEAA)

but I don't know how to do it with jsdoc:

```
const a1 = new Car('Audi A1', 4, 'petrol');
const a380 = new Plane('Airbus A380', 800, 4);

/**
 * @param {Thing} thing
 * @param {keyof Thing} prop
 */
function showProperty(thing, prop) {
    console.log(`${String(prop)}:`, thing[prop]);
}

showProperty(a1, 'capacity'); // I want to see the "power" property here...!
showProperty(a380, 'capacity'); // I want to see the "engines" property here...!
```

link to [full JS code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gbwFDV9A9AFSE57QlnnQACADmAE5gC2mEALgyqgL7TIsApqTyEa9JqwzIArswBGghn2Bh6wROwCeI3IXy7gAe2QcGM4OyMMAFAOaCANNFXrNWgJSZdZdkggAdADE9oLQALz8QgDcPnh+iIFBrmAa2hEuaqnusWQ8ukQUZGLU2rRhGGbc+ZT6uiFCGTLIACaCAGYogi25eIU+JWUVsgpKNcUGZMlZaVpNrR1dPbqoguxRDjZe2JR4DGsyDMjQCUmhvbjjuKvrKbNb3ru4++yHx6fBdzm6+flYxqZ1gAFIwAdyUGR2eHKnCMIAAXNAAOQwhhwpGOXQtRCCCCCBHI7G4-EYlaQRFI1CQUlkCBwxgUungBiknixf7gKDQADCjGgggAHuxBK0YAhuI8+sQBuJGCw2JxqhthLVZZJMCNFMpMm5tDK6HKpABrQRaIztE5acrm6Ag8Ha2hgpQDSZ4AFmCxWWyhZxfbTOR327ZxXAQGTlb1CX0zdweC6UD5BQMQyLJhjxq7QJNO9MrNbQNMPKG7F5vE7+YJpjNYP6gSAwIHgZBhQXC0VwJBoSW4fq1fUSeWVRVoPihfuGjVyLUqGN61UG9XSKdjfloLoQF2GEweyzWOxRnXZf2r1Dr4NPaBhiP7hzR3WeeO+CtBEWn5swSKv9fVqZf9-xm4T3XIsQ2gUsjnLRJgj-XFq1rbd1jAABGDJm1BHlGBsJEAEEZGxaBsKQjFoAAFmcFE1jREAkTjf4EOgMAAGYAA4AAZUMEdDGzAZssOwxAGHkGQYGwljWOItjWOcEjaKwXsSgHKRxRHSC0BwBSJwwE0zQtZTeALNFaHUgx2maSxEBMS94DBIFDKUbQbASNAA0M883W3OFBACEAjFQGwAAMABIMAAZWHPzaFcnh4X85wnNQABtSKjFoABdWi-ggazQVslL7K0GxkPIv0tBo6ICHwaAAEloFBHj1isS9BDCPwwgAIjTNqDLyhh0ngJQvICAIAEIsCymy7N6gqmLY4rZ1KuMKuq2r6pOIwmpa-roDamCIC65KIz6gahpGrAgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JSDoc annotations in TypeScript, you can use the [`@template` tag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template) to declare a type parameter for the function. This is similar to the TypeScript syntax of using angle brackets (<T>) to define a type parameter.

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {T} thing
 * @param {keyof T} prop
 */
function showProperty(thing, prop) {
    console.log(`${String(prop)}:`, thing[prop]);
}
```

[VSCode and other code editors should now be able to see all the properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwSBo.png)

Link to [modified JS code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gbwFDV9A9AFSE57QlnnQACADmAE5gC2mEALgyqgL7TIsApqTyEa9JqwzIArswBGghn2Bh6wROwCeI3IXy7gAe2QcGM4OyMMAFAOaCANNFXrNWgJSZdZdkggAdADE9oLQALz8QgDcPnh+iIFBrmAa2hEuaqnusWQ8ukQUZGLU2rRhGGbc+ZT6uiFCGTLIACaCAGYogi25eIU+JWUVsgpKNcUGZMlZaVpNrR1dPbqoguxRDjZe2JR4DGsyDMjQCUmhvbjjuKvrKbNb3ru4++yHx6fBdzm6+flYxqZ1gAFIwAdyUGR2eHKnCMIAAXNAAOQwhhwpGOXQtRCCCCCBHI7G4-EYlaQRFI1CQUlkCBwxgUungBiknixf7gKDQADCjGgggAHuxBK0YAhuI8+sQBuJGCw2JxqhthLVZZJMCNFMpMm5tDK6HKpABrQRaIztE5acrm6Ag8Ha2hgpQDSZ4AFmCxWWyhZxfbTOR327ZxXAQGTlb1CX0zdweC6UD5BQMQyLJhjxq7QJNO9MrNbQNMPKG7F5vE7+YJpjNYP6gSAwIHgZBhQXC0VwJBoSW4fq1fUSeWVRVoPihfuGjVyLUqGN61UG9XSKdjfloLoQF2GEweyzWOxRnXZf2r1Dr4NPaBhiP7hzR3WeeO+CtBEWn5swSKv9fVqZf9-xm4T3XIsQ2gUsjnLRJgj-XFq1rbd1jAABGDJm1BHlGBsJEAEEZGxaBsKQjFoAAFmcFE1jREAkTjf4EOgMAAGYAA4AAZUMEdDGzAZssOwxAGHkGQYGwljWOItjWOcEjaKwXtBkEZhaHAYU4BwEoBykWA+ASNB1LVQcTTNC1tILNFaHUgx2maSxEBMS94DBIFzKUbQbF01AA3M883W3OFBACEAjFQGwAAMABIMAAZWHELaG8nh4VC5wPIAbXioxaAAXVov4IEc0FnMy1ytBsZDyL9LQaOiAh8GgABJaBQR49YrEvQQwj8MIACI026szioYdJ4CUAKAgCABCLB8qclyhtKpi2Iq2cqrjWqGqalqTiMdrOpG6BupgiB+oyiNhtG8bJqwIA)